# How to declare gradle versions, plugins, variables to share across libraries?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, dependency-management

I want to configure for sharing dependencies and plugins.
Follows code block is to use all each projects.

```
...

plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.12"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.15.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
}

group = "dev.kunie"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
    all {
        exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j2")
        exclude("org.apache.logging.log4j", "log4j-to-slf4j")
        exclude("log4j", "log4j")
    }
}

val nexusBaseUrl = "http://localhost:9999/repository"
val NEXUS_ID = "test"
val NEXUS_PASSWORD = "test"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        credentials {
            username = NEXUS_ID
            password = NEXUS_PASSWORD
        }
        url = uri(nexusBaseUrl)
        isAllowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
}

...
```

No multi-modules structure.
Add own library that is plugin or BOM from remote (Nexus repository) something like that.

1. How to extends Spring dependency management plugin?
2. And how to publish that on Nexus repository?

Is there any examples?